# mysql connect from Synology NAS

Tags: php, mysql, nas

Trying to connect to a mysql db on a raspberry pi, from a Synology NAS.

The `SELECT` shows nothing, and the `connect.php` shows no errors.

Both work fine from a different Pi to the host Pi.

I've tried with an existing user in `phpmyadmin`, and with another, new user.
both have `%`, all IP LAN access.

```
<?php
 $db = mysqli_connect(host='192.168.1.41','user','passwd','dbase')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
?>

<html>
<!-- This is a comment -->
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h6>PHP connected</h6>
 <!-- <h6>PHP connected</h6> --> 
 </body>
```

Also tried with:

```
(host='192.168.1.41',database='dbase',user='user',password='passwd')
```

I can't see why I get neither error messages, or select query results.

Comment: `host='192.168.1.41'` here host is only for ref.?? where is your SELECT statement.

Comment: Hi Richard,
please add a bit more information about your setup. Can you reach the PI by other means (e.g. `ping`). What PHP version are you running on the Synology. Did you try with `mysql` cli client?

Comment: Select statement  ```$query  = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM readings ORDER BY Added DESC LIMIT 720) sub ORDER BY Added DESC';
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');```

Comment: I can reach the Pi from another Pi - it's been working that way for a while, just fine. My aim is to move the db hosting off Pi1, and onto the NAS.   The NAS has PHP 5.0, 7.0, and 7.2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this, [here](http://quawkle.com/synology-php-and-the-mysql-extension/)
You just have to enable the mysqli extension on the Synology 'Web Station' plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

try to add mysql or mariadb port number to your hostname

```
$db = mysqli_connect(host='192.168.1.41:3307','user','passwd','dbase')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
```